# Why can't pip uninstall pysqlite?

Tags: python, pip, pysqlite

I'm trying to remove `pysqlite` from my system using `pip`.

What I get doing so makes no sense:

```
$ pip uninstall pysqlite
```

The command worked, but watch this:

```
$ pip freeze
[...]
pysqlite==1.0.1
```

Let's try again

```
$ pip uninstall pysqlite
Can't uninstall 'pysqlite'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Nop, seems removed but still show up in `pip freeze`

Now comes the fun

```
$ pip install pysqlite
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysqlite in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Fair enough:

```
$ pip install -U pysqlite
[...]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[...]
Can't roll back pysqlite; was not uninstalled
[...]
```

I just don't get it. Why can't pip uninstall pysqlite?

Comment: *pysqlite in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages*; is this on Ubuntu and do you have `pysqlite` installed with the Ubuntu package manager?

Comment: This is on Debian 6, and I installed using pip

Comment: For Googlers: this happened to me because I'd installed the offending package with homebrew instead of pip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to your `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysqlite*.egg/` (or anywhere else you store your eggs in your python path) and look for the `installed-files.txt` file.

If it does not exists, `pip` will not be able to uninstall it, if it does, you remove all the files within and you're rid of pysqlite. And as Martijn suggests, you should also check if you did not install your package with another package manager.

If you don't have the `installed-files.txt`, and your package has not been installed through a third-part package manager, you shall look up where your egg is, and remove it from the python path. Usually, eggs also write files in the directory where they lay, so you should look for a `pysqlite/` directory in the directory where lays `pysqlite.egg`.

Comment: Thanks, the package was indeed in `/usr/lib/python/2.6/dist-packages` and that pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: If I find the .egg-link file (whichs points to /path/some/where) if I delete boths it's like `pip uninstall`?

Comment: It should, but beware that sometimes a package _can_ write in other places, and you might have stale files staying around.

Answer (score 15):

For the record, I was able to upgrade a package I was having this issue with by using the --ignore-installed flag, e.g.

```
 pip install python-dateutil --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give another way.

I pip-installed `ykdl` which requires `m3u8` and `iso8601`.

Then I wanted to uninstall them all, `pip uninstall ykdl iso8601 m3u8`.The `ykdl` and `iso8601` were gone, but I couldn't uninstall the `m3u8`.And I saw it in `pip list`. I puzzled too.

Finally.When I tried to import m3u8, it failed and said 'needs iso8601'. So i installed `iso8601`, then uninstalled `m3u8`,`iso8601` one by one. It worked

=====

It was on ubuntu. But on my Windows 10, I uninstalled `iso8601` `m3u8` `ykdl` step by step successfully. Exciting!