# How to fix problems caused by 'sudo pip install'?

Tags: python, pip

I recently encountered several problems when using docker. The problem is that, docker fails because `pip install packages` failed. Similar problems can be found at here: [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136060/why-cant-pip-uninstall-pysqlite) and [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3282).

I learnt that, it could be cause by, using `sudo pip install` or `sudo -H pip install` when trying to install packages. Also, using `sudo virtualenv` may also cause the problem.

My question is, since I've already done this before. How can I recover my system from this mess?

Mass thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this in a Docker image/container, why not just blast it and start from scratch?  (That's one of the major benefits of containerisation!)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth My system has already messed up before I use Docker. The mess made my Docker failed. It's not the docker that caused the problem.

Comment: Oh I see.  (Though I'm not sure I understand why Docker would be affected by broken Python stuff.)  FWIW, there's nothing necessarily wrong with running `pip` as the superuser.  I think you need to be a bit more specific about what the concrete symptoms are here.

Comment: Can you add your `.dockerfile`?

Comment: Issue in the third link is spefic the ubuntu 16.04 distribution due to vendored packages, I had run into a similar problem, and since its the issue due to package vendoring, the pip team did not pay heed to the issue. (Cause its caused by ubuntu package vendoring)