# ERROR: Can't roll back Pillow; was not uninstalled

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install Odoo 13.0 as source installation on Ubuntu 20.04 and running the command to install the dependencies in requirements.txt file results in the following error.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow, psycopg2
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-41u8f0do
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/
  Complete output (174 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 765, in <module>
      setup(name=NAME,
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 612, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 812, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ikueji9i
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/psycopg2/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
     35 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build Pillow psycopg2
Installing collected packages: Pillow, polib, psutil, psycopg2, pyparsing, pydot, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, python-ldap, PyPDF2, pyserial, pyusb, qrcode, reportlab, cached-property, defusedxml, isodate, requests-toolbelt, appdirs, attrs, zeep, python-stdnum, vatnumber, vobject, Werkzeug, XlsxWriter, xlwt, xlrd
  Attempting uninstall: Pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 7.0.0
    Not uninstalling pillow at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'Pillow'. No files were found to uninstall.
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gpw95zju/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/Pillow
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/
    Complete output (176 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 765, in <module>
        setup(name=NAME,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 612, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py", line 812, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Can't roll back Pillow; was not uninstalled
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-05trsp81/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gpw95zju/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to uninstall pillow but it never worked

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pillow
Found existing installation: Pillow 7.0.0
Not uninstalling pillow at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'Pillow'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: [Why can't pip uninstall pysqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136060/why-cant-pip-uninstall-pysqlite)

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to install Odoo? I had an similar problem with installing matplotlib when using `pip3 install matplotlib`.

When trying `python3 -m pip install matplotlib` it worked.

Before using this command I did an upgrade of pip and pillow but still got the mistake message.